# C# Datagridview Edit Cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to put the cursor and focus in the last row and a specific cell with the column named 'CheckNumber'. I thought I had it with this:

```
  var c = dataGridView1.RowCount;
  DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[c-1].Cells[0];
  dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
  dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
```

but it keeps coming up with this error:

Index -1 does not have a value.

Can someone please point me in the right direction!? This is driving me nuts.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the row count when this code runs?  Is it 0?

Comment: RowCount = 1 I get the error on the 'dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
' line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I am going to preface this by saying that I cannot reproduce the issue you are having.  However, you mentioned that the error actually occurs at `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;` which should have ruled out the -1 index error.

Additionally, you said that the error you get is  `Index -1 does not have a value.` That means that even though you have the right index, `cell` is still coming up as index -1.  This means either the cell does not exist, or something else sketchy is happening.  Since you sound like you've been at this for a while, I am assuming the cell actually exists.

Since the error doesn't seem to be in any of the 4 lines you've posted I would say take a look somewhere else, like when you first bind the source to the datagridview.

**Update**: I *just* found a few links relating to this. Since I don't know how you bound your datagridview, I don't really know if any of these apply, but if any do, let us know! In any case, it seems like it may apply to binding.

From: [SO Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435526/datagridview-object-databinding-issue-index-1-does-not-have-a-value)

> If you initially bind an empty
>   collection that does not inform the
>   DGV of changes (e.g. a Collection does
>   not, but a BindingList does), the
>   initial current row offset will be
>   correctly set to -1, (Because it is
>   empty.)
>
> When you subsequently add objects to
>   your data bound collection they will
>   still display correctly on the grid,
>   but the CurrencyManager will not be
>   informed of any changes, and the
>   current row offset will remain
>   stubbornly at -1.
>
> So, when you try to edit a row, the
>   CurrencyManager thinks you are trying
>   to edit a row at offset -1, and the
>   exception is thrown.
>
> To combat this, you need to rebind
>   before interacting with a row, or
>   initially bind a Collection etc when
>   it contains one or more items.

[SO Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687820/datagridview-binding-problem-index-1-does-not-have-a-value)

[.NET Monster Question](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-framework/15667/Index-1-does-not-have-a-value-DataGridView)

Answer (score 0):

Check the rowcount first, to make sure that you don't try to access a negative row number  when there aren't any rows.

```
var c = dataGridView1.RowCount;

if(c>0){  
  DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[c-1].Cells[0];
  dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
  dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true); 
}
```

Comment: My RowCount = 1, I added a wrapper to it and it doesn't stop the message. I have to have the code mixed up somewhere...